# Is Java a good choice for a streaming server application?

Tags: java, stream, audio-streaming

I'm facing a project with audio streaming, as a client and a server. Would Java be a good choice for the server app?

I've read in other questions that because of performance C++ is the best choice for this kind of app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are more comfortable with C++ or Java, I would use that.  You can write a low pause server in either language.

A streaming server is mostly about passing lots of data from A to B i.e. the I/O matters. Unless you plan to compress the stream on the fly, the CPU performance is unlikely to be important.

Even if you are doing on the fly compression and Java isn't fast enough for that, you can call a library (preferably one already written/tested) to do this via JNI and still write most of the server in Java.

Answer (score 4):

*shrug* It's not a bad choice. While audio streaming does have a performance component, the algorithms/optimizations you make are going to have a much larger effect than the language you choose.

Not to mention the famous Knuth quote "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Write in whatever you are most comfortable with and check if it's a problem later.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue with Java performance, I think, is garbage collection. Without careful consideration to what you're doing, it's easy in Java to write code that needs to pause every so often to clean up. C++ doesn't have that problem. On the other hand, without consideration of what you're doing, it's easy to write C++ code that leaks heap memory (when you forget to delete something from the heap). This is really bad for a long-running process like a server. It's possible to leak memory in Java, but it's related to keeping references around too long, not to anything built into the language.

Although C++ tends to be faster, with modern just-in-time compilers for Java, the performance difference tends to be overstated. Overall Java is probably just as fine as C++ for a streaming audio server. If you find that there's a bottleneck in some compute-intensive section, you can always drop down to C++ using [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). But that should only be after identifying a problem with profiling.

Answer (score -1):

If you did want to use java, [here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-06-1999/jw-06-media.html) would be a great place to find some uses and files for using media in java...